# all unicode characters in python

Tags: python, special-characters, txt

i want to get a list of all unicode characters for each written language as a txt file in python
is there a function / library that can help accomplish this?

here's a list to the writing systems:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_writing_system
and supported localized utf-8 code
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=globalization-supported-languages-locales

Comment: UTF8 is an encoding, not a set of characters. Do you mean unicode?

Comment: yes that's what i meant i actually found the solution here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#unichr

Comment: @Jun Um, `unichr()` doesn't exist in Python 3. It was only used [in Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unichr). Do you mean [`chr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr)?

Comment: I think this is potentially a pretty subjective question - e.g. some people who write in Arabic transliterate Arabic letters into roman letters for ease of use on computer which don't support entering Arabic letters. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_chat_alphabet Does the character '3' count as an Arabic letter?

Comment: nick -- i agree with you on this, korean is my native language and i see 
 characters that are no longer used in the modern context. i am not familiar with majority of the languages listed here, but do not want to use characters that are extinct for this project: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Hangul

Comment: Show some example of the desired output.